# ML.NET: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Column '*' with role MatrixColumnIndex should be a known cardinality U4 key, but is instead 'UInt64''

Tags: c#, ml.net

I'm following the ML.net example of Product Recommendation, but as a data source I'm using a MS Sql Database. But I'm stuck getting the following error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Column 'ProductID' with role MatrixColumnIndex should be a known cardinality U4 key, but is instead 'UInt64''

**Below is the Code:**

```
    //STEP 1: Create MLContext to be shared across the model creation workflow objects
using ConsoleAppRecommendationModel;
using Microsoft.ML;
using Microsoft.ML.Data;
using Microsoft.ML.Trainers;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

MLContext mlContext = new MLContext();

//STEP 2: Read the trained data using TextLoader by defining the schema for reading the product co-purchase dataset
var loadColumns = new DatabaseLoader.Column[]
    {
        new DatabaseLoader.Column("Label", System.Data.DbType.Single, 0),
    new DatabaseLoader.Column(nameof(ProductEntry.ProductID), System.Data.DbType.UInt64, 1),
    new DatabaseLoader.Column(nameof(ProductEntry.CoPurchaseProductID), System.Data.DbType.UInt64, 2)
    };

DatabaseLoader loader = mlContext.Data.CreateDatabaseLoader(loadColumns);//<ProductEntry>();
string sSql = "SELECT distinct NULL [Label], a.fp_dmi_fk ProductID, b.fp_dmi_fk CoPurchaseProductID FROM( SELECT fp_fh_fk, fp_dmi_fk FROM tb_F_Sale_Position WITH (nolock) WHERE (_installation = 119) AND (fp_LineType = N'M') AND (fp_Date_CloseBusinessD >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2022-03-01 00:00:00', 102)) AND (fp_wc_Status_fk = 91000002)) a inner join ( SELECT fp_fh_fk, fp_dmi_fk FROM tb_F_Sale_Position WHERE (_installation = 119) AND (fp_LineType = N'M') AND (fp_Date_CloseBusinessD >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2022-03-01 00:00:00', 102)) AND (fp_wc_Status_fk = 91000002) ) b on a.fp_fh_fk = b.fp_fh_fk and a.fp_dmi_fk <> b.fp_dmi_fk order by a.fp_dmi_fk, b.fp_dmi_fk";

DatabaseSource dbSource = new DatabaseSource(SqlClientFactory.Instance, Constants.ConnectionString, sSql);
IDataView data = loader.Load(dbSource);

var preview = data.Preview();

//STEP 3: Your data is already encoded so all you need to do is specify options for MatrxiFactorizationTrainer with a few extra hyperparameters
//        LossFunction, Alpa, Lambda and a few others like K and C as shown below and call the trainer.
MatrixFactorizationTrainer.Options options = new MatrixFactorizationTrainer.Options();
options.MatrixColumnIndexColumnName = nameof(ProductEntry.ProductID);
options.MatrixRowIndexColumnName = nameof(ProductEntry.CoPurchaseProductID);
options.LabelColumnName = "Label";
options.LossFunction = MatrixFactorizationTrainer.LossFunctionType.SquareLossOneClass;
options.Alpha = 0.01;
options.Lambda = 0.025;
// For better results use the following parameters
//options.K = 100;
//options.C = 0.00001;

//Step 4: Call the MatrixFactorization trainer by passing options.
var est = mlContext.Recommendation().Trainers.MatrixFactorization(options);

//STEP 5: Train the model fitting to the DataSet
//Please add Amazon0302.txt dataset from https://snap.stanford.edu/data/amazon0302.html to Data folder if FileNotFoundException is thrown.
ITransformer model = est.Fit(data); //Here is where the Error is showing

//STEP 6: Create prediction engine and predict the score for Product 63 being co-purchased with Product 3.
//        The higher the score the higher the probability for this particular productID being co-purchased
var predictionengine = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<ProductEntry, Copurchase_prediction>(model);
var prediction = predictionengine.Predict(
                         new ProductEntry()
                         {
                             ProductID = 2,
                             CoPurchaseProductID = 125
                         });
```

//Below is the Model:

```
public class Copurchase_prediction
{
    public float Score { get; set; }
}

public class ProductEntry
{
    [LoadColumn(0)]
    public Single Label { get; set; }

    [LoadColumn(1)]
    [KeyType(count: 262111)]
    public UInt64 ProductID { get; set; }

    [LoadColumn(2)]
    [KeyType(count: 262111)]
    public UInt64 CoPurchaseProductID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Per the error message, it wants something fitting a `U4` (presumably a 4-byte unsigned integer, so `UInt32`). `UInt64` would be right out.

Comment: If I change them to UInt32, but then in "var preview = data.Preview();" I got error: "System.InvalidCastException Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.Int32'."

Comment: Yeah, because apparently your DB uses an `Int64` (or `BIGINT`, as it's probably called there). If your data actually fits in an `INT`, add a cast to the query (`CONVERT(INT, a.fp_dmi_fkIf) AS ProductID`). If it will not fit in an `INT`, but it has less than 2^31 values so it *could*, you'll have to set up some kind of mapping from your `BIGINT` to an `INT`, for example a query with a `ROW_NUMBER()` that you then store in a separate table to join on.

Comment: I converted the data to int, so to pass the "var preview = data.Preview();" but then got the error "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Column 'ProductID' with role MatrixColumnIndex should be a known cardinality U4 key, but is instead 'UInt32''" in "ITransformer model = est.Fit(data);"

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate -- that means my original hunch was wrong. Sorry to lead you down the wrong track. I have no actual experience with ML.NET, so beyond this I don't know the proper fix.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks anyway for the help. Really appreciate it. Looks there aren't many examples using SQL, more loading from files.